# Change value of all attributes using php file

Tags: attributes

We use more than 1000 attributes in our Magento store, that all have the value is_comparable "yes".

I want to change this value to "no" for all attributes in my Magento store.

How can I achieve that, by using a file?
Otherwise I need to edit 1000 attributes by hand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run database query to make value no.

Or Just make script and add below code by all attribute id

```
require_once ('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$attributes = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection')->getItems();

foreach ($attributes as $attribute){

    $attributeId =  $attribute->getId();

    if ($attributeId) {
       $attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
       $attribute->setIsComparable(0)->save();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That script is complete and should work right away?

Comment: @HenkZ see i have edit answer. now you can use this script in root by making php file

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do I need to enter a attribute ID or something or should it work right away?

Comment: No required to add attribute id. it will take all product attribute of your store